# Use Database Triggers to create audit logs

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Are there any software packages that can work with a database to create a audit/log of all database changes.

For example, I have about 10 different tables.
I would like to log all changes made (update/deletes) to these tables a have a reporting tool that would allow me to search for an record to see the changes.

Ideally with minimal setup and configuration.
For example, the ideal tool would create a generic table to store all the changes, and not require a custom table - per table it logs. I think it could store the changes in JSON rather than separate columns.

We use SQL Azure.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your requirements please consider using [SQL Database Auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing).

A SQL Azure database feature that should consider also is [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-temporal-tables):

```
CREATE TABLE WebsiteUserInfo 
(  
    [UserID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  , [UserName] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
  , [PagesVisited] int NOT NULL 
  , [ValidFrom] datetime2 (0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
  , [ValidTo] datetime2 (0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)
 )  
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.WebsiteUserInfoHistory));
```

I don't know any third-party software that can do auditing on Azure SQL Database.